# Wicket: Submit Form in a Panel from another Panel

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I got a Page with 2 Panels (panel a and panel b). I use one of those panels (panel b) for showing some data in a table. I added a form and some checkboxes to this table. My second panel (panal a) is used for showing buttons.
I want to submit the form of panel b by pushing a button of panel a, so I can do some stuff with the checked ones.

I searched a little bit and I think I have to use an ajax submit link. But I dont get how I get my checked rows.

Page Markup:

```
<wicket:extend xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
   <div style="margin-top: 60px">
       <h2><span wicket:id="header"></span></h2>
       <div wicket:id="categoryButtonPanel"></div>
       <div wicket:id="categoryTablePanel"></div>
   </div>
</wicket:extend>
```

this is how I add my checkboxes in panel b (`categoryTablePanel`):

```
Form form = new Form("form");
final List<Category> selectedCategorys = new ArrayList<Category>(); //my list where my selected rows are in
CheckGroup group = new CheckGroup("group", selectedCategorys);

DataView dv = new DataView("categoryList", dataProvider) {

      @Override
      protected void populateItem(Item item) {
          final Category category = (Category) item.getModelObject();
          final CompoundPropertyModel<Category> categoryModel = new CompoundPropertyModel<Category>(category);

          item.add(new Check("checkBox", item.getModel()));
          // some more binded rows
 }
};
```

Markup:

```
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<form wicket:id="form">
<span wicket:id="group">
<div class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" style="overflow: auto !important;" wicket:id="categoryTable">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th><input type="checkbox" wicket:id="selector">check/uncheck all</input></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr wicket:id="categoryList">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="checkBox" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div wicket:id="paginator"></div>
    </div>
    </span>
</form>
</wicket:panel>
```

I can actually check every row, and if I create a normal button inside the form I can use the list `selectedCategorys` to do some stuff with the data.

Now I want to add one or two buttons in my second panel (`categoryButtonPanel`) to do some things with my data. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just creating the `AjaxSubmitLink` using this constructor should work:

`AjaxSubmitLink(String id, Form<?> form)`

So you need to somehow pass the form to the other panel to add it to the submitlink. Personally, I would add both the panels to a big form.

Comment: But if I put the panel into the page, I need to put the `CheckGroup` into the page too. Because I must add the checkgroup to the form. That means I need to put my List there too.

So I would need to pass my Form, Group and the selected List to my panels. It feels wrong to me. Can´t I get the selected List inside my `AjaxSubmitLink` somehow?

Comment: Why? The selection will be in panel with the form. The only thing you need is a reference to the form. You could even make a `getForm` method on the panel with the form and pass the result to the other panel

Comment: I did wrap my two panels with a form and created the form, selectedList and my checkgroup inside my page.

I only pass my selectedList to my Buttonpanel where I can use it.

Answer (score 2):

For communication you could look into wicket events, `IEventSink` and `IEvent<T>`. You can do something like this panel 1:

```
public void panel1methodCalledOnSubmit(Category payload) {
     send(getPage(), Broadcast.BREADTH, payload);
}
```

You can respond to this on panel 2 like this:

```
@Override
public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
    if (event.getPayload() instanceof Category) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This can be a little bit tricky when doing ajax things if you don't know how this works yet. Look at [this page](http://knowledgespleasure.blogspot.nl/2013/11/event-based-communication-between.html) for some more info on events.

An easier setup is what [RobAu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461499/robau) suggested. You could replace you panels with `FormComponent<T>` objects to improve the generalization of your form.

Comment: thanks! It sounds interesting and I think I´ll read some more about this.